# Azure Storage Metrics Blob Capacity not equal to file sizes

Tags: blob, azure-blob-storage

I'm pulling the data from the $MetricsCapacityBlob table in a storage account I have in azure.  I'm able to get information for the capacity but it differs from what I was expecting.

My test:
Uploaded 3 files to blob storage. 2 are 100 MB and 1 is 1MB so there's 201MB worth of data.  (They've been there for days so it's not the "it hasn't run yet" issue :) )
When I get the data from the $MetricsCapacityBlob table I get 2,007,950 bytes.

So we're looking at an expected value of: 210,763,776 bytes and getting 2,007,950 bytes.

Now the other information is accurate, the number of objects, number of containers etc.  And I'm making sure to get the data and not the analytics sizes from the table.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the capacity is the *billable capacity* and not the "total bytes included in the objects" as it deduplicates data as well as adding on minor overhead.

"Only data in unique blocks is stored/calculated.  If the 100 MB files that you are uploading are generated with dummy data then it is likely that they have lots of duplicate blocks that won't be stored."

Link to article explaining: (Scroll down to How to Estimate Capacity)
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2010/07/09/understanding-windows-azure-storage-billing-bandwidth-transactions-and-capacity.aspx

And note that the billable capacity is what is used to determine "fullness" of the blob storage container, though this number (The capacity in $MetricsCapacityBlob) is only for the blob storage and doesn't include table or other storage.

Also for anyone trying to use the metrics information remember that the metrics tables don't exist if you don't turn on metrics for the storage under the configure tab.

Comment: To clarify, user is charged for the full copy of every blob no matter how similar they are. Only snapshots are charged just the delta differences between it and the base version of the blob.